# Using $not in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
select * from table where not (a=3 and b=4 and c=3 or x=4)
```

I would expect this to work:

```
db.table.find({
  $not: {
    $or: [
      {
        $and: [
          { a: 3 },
          { b: 4 },
          { c: 3 }
        ]
      },
      { x: 4 }
    ]
  }
})
```

But it gives me an error:

```
 error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $and", "code" : 10068 }
```

Is there another way to express it in mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `{ $not : { $and : []} }` will not work (`$not` is not like other operators, can only be applied to negate the check of other operators).

$and is not the problem here, this also doesn't work (though without reporting any errors):

```
{ $not : {  a : {$gt : 14} }
```

you'd have to rewrite it to

```
{ a : {  $not : {$gt : 14} }
```

Coming back to your query:

```
`not (a=3 and b=4 and c=3 or x=4)`
```

is equivalent to:

```
a!=3 and b!=4 and c!=3 or x!=4
```

and that you can do in mongo:

```
{a : { $ne : 3}, b : { $ne : 4} ...}
```

Comment: I think you should write the query completely because you're now leaving out the important $or clause (which is needed)

Comment: The reason i'm asking this, is because i'm trying to make a sql to mongodb converter. Not easy for me i must say. But I think I got a step closer with the "equivalent" example.  It can be found here : http://klaus.dk/sqltomongodb

Comment: You're going to run into issues with trying to convert a relational query language to a document based on in a real hurry. Not worth the effort.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I don't think you mean "and" as a field will never 3 *and* 4 at the same time - it can only be 3 *or* 4. So, assuming you do want "documents where b is not 3 or 4, then you can use $nin (not in) like this:

```
db.table.find({b:{$nin: [3,4]}});
```

Comment: Arh.. bad example. Lets say it a bit more complex. Just edited my post. This is my first post on stackoverflow, so i'm messing around :p