# mongodb apply $not to $and - is there some ideas?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
select * from table where not (a=3 and b=4 and c=3 or x=4)
```

I would expect this to work:

```
db.table.find( { 
   $not : { 
      $or : [
         { $and : [ { a : 3 },
         { b : 4 },
         { c : 3 } 
      ] } ,
      { x : 4 }
   } 
 } )
```

But it is not work.

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893759/using-not-in-mongodb)

And something like this: `{a : { $ne : 3}, b : { $ne : 4} ...}`.  does
not suit me.

Because: my program takes DIFFERENT queries like this `(a=3 and b=4 and c=3 or x=4)` from users (queries to multilevel embedded objects and arrays).
And to write procedure, wich automatically apply $not to those queries looks 
long and thankless task. have you any ideas?

PS Why mongo does not have the way simply to do that?
for example, to find all the documents that match the condition, and to take from the collection of the remaining documents

Comment: Please properly indent your commands when you put them here. Its very hard to read a long JSON object in a single line. Also, what does not work? What is the output you are getting and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I am a beginner in mongo. And all seems very 
strangely. So 2 days i study how can i make 2 easy things:  1) i have 1 script for different collections and would like to add all fields in $project automatically and add to them computed fields. For example:
my collection is like this:

Comment: david, in stackoverflow i am at first time. Help below cannot help, how can i break lines in comments (   So, i can not here "properly indent my commands" (